# What should you do when you think someone can answer a question, but has not looked at the question?

Tags: feature-request

When you are researching a topic, before asking a question on SO, you check on whether that question has already been asked (even indirectly). If not, then you ask.

After asking and waiting, what if you do not get a relevant answer? On reading responses/answers to related/relevant questions, you might think "this guy would probably be able to answer the question better/best." But he has not answered or even commented on the question. Maybe he has been busy (in which case you cannot do anything), but maybe — since there are so many questions on SO — your question skipped his eye.

There should be a way in which we can ping or poke "that guy," to tell him about the question.

There is a spam fear factor, when you poke a guy again and again, or poke for irrelevant questions.

The team can come up with a mechanism to prevent people from spamming others with irrelevant questions, but I think if the other person feels disturbed/spammed, he can vote the question down, ask for it to be closed, with his comments specifying the reason, and a moderator or even the community can take care of it with five votes to close. I think.

Answer (score 23):

IMHO, I personally, do not like to be "pinged" out of the blue (in an open comment *by someone who I really don't know*) regarding whether or not I have already seen a question and/or whether I can answer it.

In fact, I think it is a bit rude, especially, if it just a comment containing a link, without any explanatory text for context.

Maybe I am being a bit too touchy about it, but here are my reasonings:

- If it is a site that I am rather active on, then chances are that I've already seen it... and if I haven't answered it, then that's because I can't, or am unable to (they are not necessarily the same thing).
- If it is a site that I am not active on, it is probably because I don't have sufficient free time, so poking me and begging me to answer a question is likely to annoy me.

On the other hand, *if* I already know the person and/or have another communication route (i.e chat room, they know my email or can reach me on some other communication channel) then a friendly poke is fine.

---

I would suggest also reading:

- [this highly voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40884/280335) to [What's the best way to invite a user to answer a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40879/280335)
- [Invite someone to answer a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210946/280335)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what you think gives you the right to pester someone who volunteers their time here to help others. I follow the tags for things that I want to be aware of, read questions when I see them, and answer those that I can (or I have time for at the moment). I'd find it very irritating to be pinged by people I don't know asking me for help - it's annoying enough as it is getting pinged after I leave a comment asking for details to a low-quality question (whether I might be able to answer it or not, I can spot low quality) by the poster telling me they edited to add the details and I should answer it now.

This is not (and never has been) a social networking site, which is why there is no ability present to ping users at will - the site is not intended to be used like a forum or chat room or discussion site. The SE network sites are staffed by volunteers, and when and how those volunteers spend their time should be up to them, without being nagged or having their inboxes spammed with *plz help me now* requests.

Answer (score 8):

The SO community is based on allowing user's to answer at the leisure and desire. If you are not getting the responses you want to a question there are a few things you can do. First of all, make sure you question is worded well and explains directly and clearly what it is you need help with. Additionally, if you have continued working on the problem yourself, posting what you have tried (successful or not) will help show people that you're working to solve the problem yourself and may also provide more direction to potential answerers as far as what you're looking for. There is not a way, nor would I expect there to be in future, to specific "ping" one user; but if you make your question good enough, it likely will get seen by someone who can help you.

Comment: When I ask a question I've usually exhausted my other resources and gone through quite a lot of trial and error etc. so "working" on the question and editing it (and in turn bumping it up) doesn't really work.

Answer (score 8):

We already have *Unanswered Questions* -> *My Tags* to show you questions with the tags where you are active that have no up-voted answer.  Perhaps we could highlight this feature better?

Answer (score 8):

I don't particularly like the idea of the system sending an email, IM, whatever to me whenever someone thinks I can answer a question.

I wonder if it would be possible to simply flag the question for a particular user.  You flag a question for user x's attention and next time they login they see a bar at the top of the screen like you see when you have new comments/answers.

Answer (score 2):

While emailing the person *may* been seen as a little intrusive, if you know that user's on Twitter I don't think it's unreasonable to tweet "@foobar: I think this question is right up your street. Care to have a look? http://..." I know that's happened to me a couple of times, and it wasn't a problem at all.

Comment: hmm this is surely one way and good one too, but not everyone use twitter, and how to find that guy on twitter if he is using bare information of himself in his profile page.

Comment: I agree, if you have some other "relationship" with a person, I have no problem contacting the user outside of the site, but internal to the site, I don't think it's something that should be supported.

Comment: Users who are cool with being contacted have contact info in their profiles. If you se a Twitter handle, email address etc then you can use it to tell them about the question. If you don't, then you have to accept that you can't contact them directly. I've found that @-ing people on Twitter works well, attracting both the @-ed person and others.