# Invite someone to answer a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Although Quora and Stack Overflow work in different domains, both inherently share one common thing, they are Q & A sites.

One feature that Quora has, which I believe is not on Stack Overflow (or I was not able to find it) is *Ask To Answer*, inviting someone to answer a question.

I am not talking about bounties, but a general request to someone to answer a question, that just might have gone ignored by people (as it happened to me of late). A person might not be willing to offer a bounty, in which case, their question remains unanswered.

Comment: By invite someone, you mean a specific user who already is active on Stack Overflow?  Or do you mean someone that you know who might not be a member and you think could answer the question?

Comment: Jon Skeet might be interested in this feature :)

Comment: @psubsee2003..Someone already active...

Comment: @alphacentauri ok, then no way.  You'll have thousands of people inviting (i.e bugging) a handful of high profile users.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40879/182868, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5006/182868

Comment: There are already bounties, taking rep cap to be top-rep user you need to be a bounty hunter

Comment: I'd better leave meta...This post is giving me nightmares...:P

Comment: This is an ***excellent*** question - not for the concept, but to illustrate (and highlight) the *horrific nightmare* of being constantly pinged for answers by random users in the comments of unrelated posts.

Answer (score 22):

No.

Lets put this to a thought experiment:

Suppose this feature existed. I have a question about technology X, and I can see who the top reputation user in this particular tag is. I have not gotten any answer, so will ask that user to answer it.

I do that, **but so does everyone else** with an issue on this tag.

Result:

High rep user gets thousands of requests to answer questions, some of which they can answer, some they can't and most of which are simply too many for them to be able to answer - they get flooded with requests.

They leave, never to come back to answer anything ever again.

Comment: Maybe the impact could be softend by installing a system where interested users in a given topic can be indirectly invited.... Wait! That's already there and called 'tags'. :)

Answer (score 8):

In general if a question is ignored it is because (a) it is not sufficiently clear or (b) it is in a very small field and no one that could answer it has seen it. If (a) improve it, if (b) tag it using the correct tags, people interested in those fields will browse them.

This suggestion would lead to simply bugging famous users to answer questions. Very quickly these users would leave the site

Comment: ... or (c) it was swamped by a host of "please do my coding" or "where is the typo" type of questions.

Comment: "Very quickly these users would leave the site". **Exactly!!**